# Continuous Integration/Deployment - MEAN Stack Project based on 2 Git Repositories

Tags: angularjs, git, continuous-integration, travis-ci, mean-stack

I am starting a new project using the MEAN Stack. The front-end and the back-end are in 2 different git repositories, hosted on bitBucket. Each project/repo has its own unit/e2e tests. The Backend is a Restful JSON API and the front-end is an AngularJS SPA. A grunt task is available in the front-end project to output an optimised/minified version of the client code.

My idea would be to first run the unit/e2e tests on the client's code, then the  "grunt deploy" task, then somehow automatically commit the result of this grunt task into the backend project/git repo, run the unit test of the backend code and finally deploy the backend project on Amazon.

I am not too sure how to setup this kind of project on platforms like Travis or Codeship as it's using 2 GIT repo instead of one...

If anyone has any experience/recommendation for a setup like this one, that would be really appreciated.

Cheers,

Niko

Comment: Try something and ask a specific question when you can't get it to work. You could use an after_script on one project to trigger the build of the other, but it looks like you should simply dump the idea of two git repos and put all the code into one. Or at least use a nested repository to have a single travis build work with both git repos.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid hand-crafted solutions as much as possible, e.g. copying/committing files across repositories - this will only lead to pain and a maintenance nightmare. Use a standard tool for this.

The standard way of handling dependencies like these is using a dependency management tool. On the backend, you typically do this using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), which you are probably already familiar with - you're probably using it for pulling in build tools like Grunt.

When building front end applications, you typically use [Bower](http://bower.io/).

With Bower, you define a `bower.json` file and list your dependencies there. In your case, you would need a `bower.json` file in both projects:

- In your front-end project, the `bower.json` file defines the name of your package, the version, its most important files, etc.
- In your back-end project, the `bower.json` file defines the dependencies, i.e. your front-end project.

When defining the dependency to your front-end project, you can either point it to a publicly available package from the Bower registry (e.g. Angular), or to a Git repo (which is probably what you're looking for). You can point it to Git tag (e.g. `#1.2.3`), or to a Git branch (e.g. `#master`). You don't need to register your package in the public Bower registry if you don't want to.

You would need to include `bower install` as an additional build step in your back-end project, ideally after running `npm install`.

Again, try to avoid workarounds, try to stick to the standard tools. Splitting your work into two separate Git repos is perfectly fine, it's a good practice for keeping project size manageable - you just need to use the right tools to get things done.

Here are some tutorial links for getting started with Bower:

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-bower-in-your-next-project--cms-20526
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-bower